# VS code: tell omnisharp which project/solution to work on

Tags: visual-studio-code, project, solution, omnisharp

I have a workspace with several unrelated folders in it. I don't get any C# code checks (errors marked red and such). I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62847588/5333340) and checked the output of the OmniSharp log which only contained info about the topmost project in my workspace. This issue is addressed [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1889) as well, and I tried following its [solution](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1889#issuecomment-347341566) saying that one just needs to switch the project:

[image]

Unfortunately, my VScode has neither a project selector in the bottom-right of the status bar nor a project picker at the top:

[image]

Or maybe it has, but I don't see it anywhere.

**How do I get (any of those) project pickers for my VS code?**

**How do I tell OmniSharp to work on a project/solution of my choice?**

I have VS Code version 1.63.2 according to Help -> About.

Comment: The answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55535177/5333340) post have helped me solve it. I had to take the latest OmniSharp, install a missing .net framework that I was targeting and restart OmniSharp.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl + Shift + P in VS Code.
Type “OmniSharp: Select Project” and press Return.
Select the top level sln or csproj